# How to pop out a WPF control from the flow and bring it to the first plane

Tags: wpf

I have an application that present data in a summarized way. The structure of the view itself is not trivial, but not really complicated either (ie, a user control in a tems control, in a stackpanel,in a grid, etc). I want that when clicked the usercontrol pops out to the front plane and grows to show all the details (with an animation, like a plane flip or something alike).

Idealy, the user control should be duplicated so that the original one stays in place, and needs to stay in the application window boundaries. If modal, even better.

I'm looking for pointers on how to achieve this, not necessarily a detailed walkthrough. I'm not interested in commercial products, even if it means I need to reinvent the wheel. I had a look on many quite similar questions on SO, but haven't found anything useful so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboard can get you the animation you need. Panel.ZIndex will allow you to set it on top of the other controls like you would in a web page. A sample of this with a Canvas can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/06/13/controlling-zorder-using-the-zindex-property.aspx

Comment: I could indeed use a specific control that will get animated and use the canvas to bring it to the first plane. Using the control datacontext will even assure that everything is bind the right way. I'm gonna try that in the next few days and if no better solution arise, I'll accept your answer. Thank you.